# Publisher Action in Outlook Side Panel

Tags: outlook, salesforce

I am trying to make create contact publisher action available in Outlook side panel. I have created a new publisher layout added the action in the layout and assigned it to the profile. But still in outlook the action is not showing up.. Is there any other configuration required other than the one i have mentioned ?

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved by setting the records type in the global actions.